# Make headway in/on/into/with?

Tags: prepositions, phrasal-verbs, prepositional-phrases

I'm having a difficulty using the right preposition with the phrase "make headway". When I looked the word up from online Oxford and Cambridge Dictionaries, I found they use different prepositions.

[they appear to be making headway in bringing the rebels under control](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/headway)

[So far it seems that negotiations are not making headway on a key issue.](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/headway)

[I'm trying to learn to drive, but I'm not making much headway (with it).](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/headway?q=make%20headway)

[Little headway has been made so far in the negotiations.](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/headway?q=make%20headway)

Haven't I noticed the use of "with, on, and into" prepositions, I would normally use the preposition "in". Is there a specific rule?

Comment: Those all seem perfectly fine. I doubt you will find a "rule" here, but I realize that is no help to a non-native speaker.

Comment: @tchrist 
Does that mean there is room for options?

Comment: Yes, I think perhaps so. I'd have to run any given sentence over in my head a few times different ways to say for sure what sounds ok or not in that particular sentence.

Comment: With works for all options, in works with gerunds, in and on work with nouns (but not pronouns) as a rough guide but I don't think there is a rule.

Answer (score 3):

It seems the idiom 'make headway' can be followed by any preposition as required by the context, without any sort of restriction.

> **Definition of make headway**:  ***to move forward or make progress***(https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/make%20headway)
>
> The wind kept the boat from making headway **toward** shore.>
>
> The boat made little headway **against** the strong current.>
>
> We're gradually making headway **with** the project.>
>
> They've recently made some headway **in** their search for a cure.>

Comment: I'm gonna guess you can't make headway backwards.

Comment: @deadrat - I don't get your comment.

Comment: Headway is forward motion. A preposition that indicates backward motion wouldn't be idiomatic.